# Is it possible to have a conditional *as* clause in a db2 SQL statement?

Tags: sql, database, db2

```
select 
    tableName.fieldField as <Tomorrow's Date>
from tableName
fetch first 2 rows only;
```

I would like the "as" clause to make the column name tomorrow's date:

```
date(current date + 1 days)
```

Are conditional column names possible using only a SQL query to a DB2 database?

Comment: I'd be astonished if that were possible.  The alias name should be an identifier (possibly a delimited identifier).

Comment: only if you generate the sql using sql (dynamic sql), and I cannot bring myself to recommend doing that for a column heading.

Comment: I didn't think it was possible. Also, I don't think the column name can start with a number. So, I don't even know how to _non-conditionally_ achieve this at the outputted record-set level.

Comment: Dynamic SQL could be used as noted by @user2067753 (and properly qualified as a poor idea for the situation). The heading could be generated as something like "July_23". It's not clear how it would be used.

Comment: If you delimited it, you can probably use anything.  I'd just use `AS Tomorrow` in a standard static query, though - for one thing, any application will have an easier time using a constant column identifier.  Side note: without an `ORDER BY`, you're going to get 2 "random" rows (which you can't control).